# How to convert maximo SQL for Crystal Reporting

Tags: crystal-reports, maximo

How do I change this to work in crystal?

```
SELECT jpnum in (select jpnum from jobplan minus select jpnum from jobtask where jptask = '1')
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to structure this query and I'm not completely sure of the structure of your tables, but this query should get you on the way to a command.

```
SELECT
    JOBPLAN.JPNUM,
    MIN(ISNULL(JOBTASK.JPTASK,0))
FROM
    JOBPLAN
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    JOBTASK
    ON JOBPLAN.JPNUM = JOBTASK.JPNUM
GROUP BY
    JOBPLAN.JPNUM
HAVING
    MIN(ISNULL(JOBTASK.JPTASK,0)) <> 1
```

Comment: I tried to run it but it says "ISNULL': invalid identifier.

Comment: hmm.  What version of crystal reports are you running?

Comment: I thought it was 8.5 but the help screen says 'Introduction to SAP Crystal Reports 2011'.

Comment: I tested the code above, so it does work. Not sure what the issue is.

Comment: Thank you.  I will investigate further.